# Symfony2 Functional Test - GeomFromText / SQLite

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a situation where I need to write functional/unit tests on entities that rely on MySQL's spatial functions.  However, my test environment uses SQLite for testing (Using LiipFunctionalTestBundle).  There is a [SpatiaLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/%20SpatiaLite) extension for SQLite, but not sure if it's possible to use this with wampserver?  Does anyone have experience with a similar situation?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**  In the meantime, I have switched to MySQL for test cases.